# Multiple bounds on a generic type in method declaration doesn't compile in Java 8

Tags: java, generics, inference

The following compiles in **Java 7** but not **Java 8**:

```
interface Handler<A,B> {}

class SomeClass<T> {

    public <E> void doSomething(Class<E> typeV, T valueT) {
        E valueE = null;
        doSomethingElse(typeV, valueE, valueT);
    }

    private <X, Y, Z extends Enum<Z> & Handler<X,Y>> void doSomethingElse(Class<X> typeX, X valueX, Y valueY) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

This is the error I am seeing:

> > The method doSomethingElse(Class, X, Y) in the type SomeClass is not applicable for the arguments (Class, E, T)

It *does* compile if I remove the **class** bound:

```
interface Handler<A,B> {}

class SomeClass<T> {

    public <E> void doSomething(Class<E> typeV, T valueT) {
        E valueE = null;
        doSomethingElse(typeV, valueE, valueT);
    }

    private <X, Y, Z extends /* Enum<Z> & */ Handler<X,Y>> void doSomethingElse(Class<X> typeX, X valueX, Y valueY) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

I'm using **Eclipse Luna 4.4.0** and **JDK 8u102**. Any idea what's going wrong here? Is this a bug?

Comment: You're never using `Z` in the arguments.  What's the point?

Comment: Compiles for me in Neon 4.6.1 and JDK 8u65.

Comment: I am in my production code. This is just a simple example replicating the problem.

Comment: I have noticed this kind of problem in 8u45 (I believe), but fixed in a subsequent upgrade.

Comment: Then you left out the piece of production code that's causing the problem in your example, it's likely the usage of `Z`. Please make sure your example actually shows the problem.